# rhc port forward - open shift issue

Tags: java, openshift, portforwarding, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to port forward a particular application that I am developing for. In open shift I have the following applications available;

[image]

If i choose hotornot then i get the following when running this command in the terminal rhc

> port-forward -a jbossas

[image]

if i run the same command but replace hotornot with the other application name (jbossas) - i get the following

[image]

Does anyone know why i can't port forward the second application but i can the first?

Thanks

Comment: Are you closing the first port-forward before opening the second?

Comment: yes - there running completely independently - i am using the same terminal so have to exit one before running another

Answer (score 0):

turns out i had to first login with a terminal via ssh
then via another terminal i needed to run port forward but not just with the application name, i needed the domain name - in this instance rhc port-forward -a jbossas -n secondstory1d

then i needed to log out of the ssh terminal and then re port forward again :/