# Openshift binding a TCP port with port forward?

Tags: sockets, tcp, openshift, spring-integration, portforwarding

according to [this doc](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html)

Does this mean we could port forward 8000 and  8443?
If I deploy a spring integration project with TCP port binding to 8000 or 8443, will I able to telnet to openshift?

I have tried, but not sure what happened. When I use putty RAW mode connect to 8443, and send some text, nothing happened on the server console, my program should print out what it received. so I suppose I failed, right?

P.S. that project was tested using localhost tomcat, it works locally.

this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789238/rhc-port-forward-open-shift-issue) seems to successfully forwarding many port.

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting [the linked doc](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html); you can bind your app to 8080 (not to 8000 or 8443), all traffic received on 8000 and 8443 will be routed by the proxy to your app listening on 8080. If your app is supposed to log to console everything it receives, you probably want to `rhc tail <yourApp>` to see the output.

Comment: I am trying to create non-standard socket to listen to TCP. but I give up on openshift now, seems like openshift only support what you've mention, that is 8000 and 8443 for http server only.